# NASM cannot declare initialized data

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64

For some reason I am unable to complie nasm program. If I try to put something in .data section it errors out: 
`error: comma expected after operand 1` (if I declare signle variable), or 
`error: parser: instruction expected` if array declared.

My code (include libs, declare data, return 0 and ret):

```
%include "../asm64_io/asm64_io.inc"

segment .data
label dw 1000             ; word labeled L2 with initial value 1000
segment .bss
segment .text
global asm_main
asm_main:
enter 0,0
;
mov rax, 0 ; return 0
leave
ret
```

Then I compile with

```
    nasm -f elf64 prog.asm -o prog.o
    gcc -o prog prog.o ../asm64_io/driver64.o ../asm64_io/asm64_io.o
```

I can declare if I don't use asm64 and use _start label as entry point.

asm64_io.inc:

```
extern  read_int, read_string, read_char
extern  print_int,  print_string, print_char
extern  println_int,  println_string, println_char, print_nl 
extern  sub_dump_regs, sub_dump_mem, sub_dump_math, sub_dump_stack
%macro  dump_regs 1
push      qword %1
call      sub_dump_regs
%endmacro
```

Comment: Did you try a label name other than `label`?  That's probably a keyword or already defined as a macro.

Comment: Also, don't use the `enter` instruction; it's really slow.  (Unless you're optimizing for code-size at the expense of everything else, and you can't omit the frame pointer.  But you're obviously not doing that, because you didn't use `xor eax,eax` to zero RAX efficiently)

Comment: @PeterCordes I am just trying to learn nasm. Other name does not change anything.

Comment: I copy-pasted your source (without the `%include` line) into `foo.asm`.  It assembles just fine with `nasm -felf64 -Worphan-labels -g -Fdwarf foo.asm`.  This isn't a [mcve]; your posted code doesn't produce the errors you describe.  What line is the error on?  And does it go away for you if you leave out the `%include`?

Comment: Is the code you are showing in this question exactly the code that fails on your computer? Is it possibly you have declared a string with a single quote in it?

Comment: @PeterCordes : his question says **I can declare if I don't use asm64 and use _start label as entry point** so I assume from that the issue is when he's using asm64_io.inc .

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I copy-pasted the `asm64_io.inc` contents into `../asm64_io/amd64_io.inc` and tried again with the OP's entire source.  Still assembles fine with NASM, no warnings or errors.  Voting to close as no [mcve].

Comment: @PeterCordes The problem is that I need it to work with include. I can write program that operates on stdin and it works fine, but as soon as I something in .data it spits out compiler errors.

Comment: [edit] your question to something that *actually* produces errors.  This doesn't.

Comment: @PeterCordes It works for me, and I also have driver64 and amd64_io objects (found them online in github) . The reason I asked him for his copy of the `.inc` was because mine worked and I wanted to see his. He's either using some version of NASM that has some bug that makes things different from us or his code is different than what he posted here.

Comment: I assume you aren't on an MacOS system logged into a Linux computer.

Comment: I made new directory downloaded my code from stack and still errors out. Apparently my system must be broken ;/ Sorry, I thought it's mistake in code, I am learning nasm.

Comment: Can you show us an example of the exact program you are using that fails with an error. I'm beginning to think the example code you posted here is not what you are actually using

Comment: @MichaelPetch I downloaded my code from stack overflow and there is error :( I guess I'll reinstall my system

Comment: For example if you create a variable with a label without putting a colon after it and that name happens to be an x86 instruction weird things will happen.

Comment: You say you get an error if you add an array in the data section. Can you tell us exactly what the line looks like that defines that array?

Comment: `label dw 1000`
I've tried other names, and it doesn't matter

Comment: What Distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: Are you sure you used a semicolon for the `comment` you put on that line?

Comment: Cent OS 7
I think that system is broken, because I was able to compile examples provided by my lecturer, but now I checked them and they're broken. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: That's weird, NASM is normally a pretty stable package.  For the record, I tested with NASM version 2.13.01.  (On Arch Linux).

Comment: I built a copy of Nasm 2.10.07 that CentOS 7 uses on my Debian system and it works.

Comment: I can only guess that the `inc` file is corrupt somehow. It is the only thing that makes any sense.

Answer (score 3):

I turned out that text I copied from manual had some invisible Unicode characters that messed compiler up.

Comment: FWIW, NASM, MASM, YASM etc. are generally called assemblers, not compilers.